# Overlaying scatter plots in R (unable to use melt)

Tags: r

after much searching I am unable to find what I am looking for;

I want to use 2 columns in a 18x32 dataframe to have scatter plots. Imagine a df like this;

```
df

V1 V2 V3 V4 V1.1 V2.1 V3.1 V4.1
 1  1  2  1   1    1    2    1 
 2  3  2  3   2    3    1    2
 4  4  1  1   4    5    5    7
```

Now I need to scatter plot (on the same graph - i.e. overlay);

```
X from 1:3, Y = V2 and X from 1:3, Y = V2.1
```

So I can try using ggplot;

```
plot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = 1:3, y = V2) + geom_point()

plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = 1:3, y = V2.1) + geom_point()
```

I basically need to combine plot1 and plot 2.

The problem with using the melt function is that the real data frame has 18 rows and 32 columns (the first 16 are estimates, and the next 16 are the p values of those estimates).

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the following method

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = 1:3, y = V2)) + geom_point() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x=1:3, y = V18.1), colour = 'red')
```

Thanks!